# Python 3 filter - Bug or Feature?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, filter, grep

Okay, I am a complete newbie to Python - and stackoverflow.  I am coming from a ksh and Perl background.

The following in an interactive session with Python 2.7:

```
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
    [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import re
    >>> KEY="REC_PAPER"
    >>> VALIDVALUES=filter(lambda x:re.search(r'^' + KEY + '\=', x), [
    ... "REC_METAL=|YES|NO|",
    ... "REC_PAPER=|YES|NO|",
    ... "REC_GLASS=|YES|NO|",
    ... "REC_PLAST=|YES|NO|",
    ... "DEBUG_FLAG=|0|1|"
    ... ])  #End general list.
    >>> print(VALIDVALUES)
    ['REC_PAPER=|YES|NO|']
    >>>
```

Which is what I would expect VALIDVALUES to return.  However, Python 3.2's interactive session yields completely different results:

```
    Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 17:02:41) 
    [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import re
    >>> KEY="REC_PAPER"
    >>> VALIDVALUES=filter(lambda x:re.search(r'^' + KEY + '\=', x), [
        ... "REC_METAL=|YES|NO|",
        ... "REC_PAPER=|YES|NO|",
        ... "REC_GLASS=|YES|NO|",
        ... "REC_PLAST=|YES|NO|",
        ... "DEBUG_FLAG=|0|1|"
        ... ])  #End general list.
    >>> print(VALIDVALUES)
    <filter object at 0xb734268c>
    >>>
```

I have seen in several places (including stackoverflow) where Python's equivalent of Perl's grep against a list is to filter the list.  That appeared to work in Python 2.  However, assuming the above behaviour in Python 3 is "correct," that no longer seems to be the case.

First question:  Is the above beahviour a bug or feature in Python 3?

Second question:  Assuming it is a feature, how do I get the output that Python 2 was giving?  For reasons I won't go into, I want to stay away from defining a function or subroutine, and do it "inline" like the current code.

Am I missing something obvious (quite possible for a newbie)?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#filter), `filter` in Python 3.x returns an *iterator*, rather than a list as in [version 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). This is more memory-efficient than generating the whole list up-front. If you want the list back, you can wrap the iterator in a `list()` call:

```
VALIDVALUES = list(filter(...))
```

Alternatively, and as recommended by [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), you could rewrite it as a list comprehension without a `lambda`:

```
VALIDVALUES = [x for x in [...] if re.search(r'^' + KEY + '\=', x)]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  This is intended behaviour (a feature), and there is a way to get the desired result (via list()).  I had a feeling there was a piece (like list()) that I was missing.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't usually need a list of values. You can directly loop the output like below

```
for value in VALIDVALUES:
  do_some_thing(value)
```

or

```
for value in filter(...):
  do_some_thing(value)
```

Sometimes you may need unique values or non mutable values. Use `set` or `tuple` or `frozenset` instead of `list` as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867960/463758).